# Python error when attempting to insert/update type(int) back into nested list after conversion from string

Tags: python, insert, int, element

I need to access and convert element 3 in a nested list created from a txt file.

I am absolutely new at python, and can read list comprehension, at this stage I have a preference for the 'long script' as it helps me visualise.

The element is a string type.  It contains either a word which I have to capitalise or a number as well as `$` symbol to strip.

My loop works and when I `print(x)` I get a successful print of the value I need to access.

I can successfully achieve all formatting. `$` is stripped, the word is `capitalised` with an if statement inside the loop, and I am using `isdigit()` to successfully identify and convert `string` to `int(x)`.

Where I am failing, majorly are the many attempts to take the value of (x) and insert it back into my list[3]

Is my inexperience showing?

I have tried many variations on the them but the major error of `int type is not subscriptable` plagues me.

It is my understanding that lists are mutable and can hold various types, am I correct?

Here is my code.

```
del list[3]
list.insert(3, x)
list[3] = x
if list[3] !='':
    list[3] = x
```

## Not the actual list.

```
propertyList = [[ some , text , 23424], [other , 3234 , replaceme],[text, floatreplace, 99.33]] 
for x in propertyList:
  x = x[3]
  x = x.strip('$')

  try:
    if "." in x :
      x = float(x)
      print(x, "Yes, user input is a float number.")
    elif(x.isdigit()):
      x = int(x)
      del propertyList[3]
      propertyList.insert(3, x)
      print(x, "Yes, input string is an Integer.")
    else:
     if x == 'auction':
      x = x.capitalize()
      print(x)
  except ValueError:
    print(x, 'is type',type(x))
# propertyList[3].replace(x)
print(propertyList)

return
```

I hope to replace the string element with my new formatted and converted int element.

`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Hi Adrian. Can you provide an example of the input to this code that produces that error?

Comment: It is all automated in the code above.  It reads in the list and then iterates through the above code which produces the error.  As I couldn't upload the txt file I created a the sample list, but this is my first post and it put it above the code =(  I was also an element short as it starts at 0, so my code shoud read [2] instead of three to recreate the error.

Comment: From my latest reading a list is mutable, but a string within that list is not??  So I need to, perhaps, append (x) into a the nested list at the end, and then delete element 3 from the nested list?  Is this possible? Or was my first approach closer.  thanks for the assist mapeters.

Comment: So sorry,  my copy and paste didn't capture the function title at the top and line at the bottom calling it.   Its function name was def formatElement():  and it was called with formatElement()  Sorry, I am still reading up on adding code into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are replacing elements in the outer list, not the sublist. When you do `del propertyList[3]`, that is deleting an entire sublist.

To delete from the sublist, you need to use a separate variable name for the sublist and the element in the list, so start off like this:

```
for sublist in propertyList:
    x = sublist[3]
```

And then change these lines to modify `sublist` instead of `propertyList`:

```
del propertyList[3]
propertyList.insert(3, x)
```

However, it is much simpler to replace the element just by doing this:

```
sublist[3] = x
```

Comment: Magic!  Thanks for the assist!  I went with the easier one you suggested and placed an individual one, with each if statement so x was updated at the time.  Thank you very much. Too many hours on this one =)

Comment: End edit, I also changed my for statement to match the answer in my supplied code.

Comment: @AdrianJuhl great, glad to help! For the future, I would recommend using a debugger or adding more print statements to print out the state of things. If you printed out `propertyList` on each iteration, you could see how it was getting modified incorrectly. Just a tip!